# How to get Social Features working on my site?

Tags: social

I had Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 and in May 2011, I successfully migrated to SharePoint 2010.

Now, I have the following

1. SharePoint 2010 for Internet Sites with SP1
2. Form Based Authentication is used for User Management (Claim-based auth)

There are many Social features like My Sites, Tagging, Bookmarks, Note board, Organization browser, Ratings etc which are not working.

Can someone please let me know from where to start? i.e. What *steps* I need to follow to get all features working from currently where I am (i.e. FBA Claim based auth)?

By steps, I mean what should I get first? User Profile System or Active Directory Auth etc. Any article explaining the steps would be of a great help!

Comment: It would really help to have details in your question rather than "not working". What doesn't work? What symptoms do you receive? Is there one specific question you can ask here? Otherwise this is a broad question that is likely to be closed. Please [edit] it with this additional information.

Comment: I have given as much information as possible. I wanted to get MySites working on the site using FBA claim based. Since MySites Host is not installed there are obviously no symptoms for this. @Mike have given exact reply I was looking for. Hence not editing the question. Thanks!

Comment: Next time, please make sure you have all relevant information **in your question** and ask a **single, specific** question. This way your problem is more easily found by others and better helps the community at large. See [ask] for more details. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to deploy the User Profile Service Application.  Within there you need to configure MySites (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262500.aspx)

Update:  Additional details provided in comments:
You need to have the MySite host accessible to the FBA users. If they are getting a 404, then I don't believe the MySite Host has been deployed. The link I provided will assist you with the required configuration. If the MySite Host is configured for internal users, but not FBA, then extend the site as GavinB suggested. User Profile Sync should not be a requirement.

Comment: Thx. Does it means I have to get FBA to Active Directory migration then User Profile Service working and then the Social Features?

Comment: MySites can work under claims with FBA.

Comment: Oh Wow! Can you please share more details (artilce etc) on MySites with FBA?

Comment: Extend the web app running MySites to use FBA

Comment: @saumilm - You need to have the MySite host accessible to the FBA users.  If they are getting a 404, then I don't believe the MySite Host has been deployed.  The link I provided will assist you with the required configuration.  If the MySite Host is configured for internal users, but not FBA, then extend the site as GavinB suggested.  User Profile Sync should not be a requirement.

Comment: @GavinB and Mike: you both have good (and I believe correct answers) sitting here in comments. I urge you to post them as answers!

Comment: @MikeOryszak - Just to update you - Your information has helped me to get My Sites working.

Answer (score 1):

There is a farm feature called `Social Tags and Note Board Ribbon Controls`. Is this enabled?

Central Administration > System Settings > Farm Management > Manage Farm Features

Comment: Yes, its enabled but when I click on the tags it gives error 404. Even MySites is not working...

Comment: Is there a more detailed error message in the logs? Perhaps the actual path of what the browser is trying to retrieve?

Comment: Nothing specific in logs. Does Tags & Noteboard require User Profile sync working?

Comment: Are you at least seeing the 404 error in the log file?