# how to enable like it and tags & notes in sharepoint 2010

Tags: ribbon, social

my sharepoint site doesn't have i like it and tags & notes. i am already active Sharepoint Feature on Central Administrator "Social Tags and Note Board Ribbon Controls" but still not appear.. my question is how to enable "i like it and tags & notes"?

Answer (score 0):

These feature are, as best I can recall linked to the the User Profile Service Application and the MySites.

There is another thread within Stack Exchange that may be a good place to start.

[How to get Social Features working on my site?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18979/how-to-get-social-features-working-on-my-site?rq=1)